# Accessing an object name from within the object

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I'm wondering whether there is a way to access the name of an object within the object itself.

```
let object = {a: {test: ()=>{ console.log(?); }}}
object.a.test() // should give me 'a'
```

In this example I would like to print the name of the object (`'a'`) in the `console.log` call.

Comment: That's not really a meaningful thing to do in JavaScript. The object (the value of  `object.a`) doesn't have any real lasting relationship to that particular property of `object`; it just happens to be its value. It could be the value of any number of other properties of other objects, or variables.

Comment: You already know it's name, "a", so why do you need to get it programmatically? (I think this is an XY problem, you should really show us your actual usecase)

Comment: It's just something that might have been useful. But I guess I should rather restructure my program so I don't need this.

Answer (score -2):

You can use normal functions and loop through keys of the main parent `object` and check if its value is equal to `this`

```js
let object = {
  a:{
    test: function(){ 
      console.log(Object.keys(object).find(x => object[x] === this)); 
    }
  }
}
object.a.test()
```

Comment: You're misusing the `this` keyword. It won't always work like you're expecting (e.g. try executing `(function () { object.a.test(); }())` instead).

Comment: @PedroCorso it will work if `object` is available

Comment: @adiga Sorry, bad example. But say that you want to pass `object.a.test` as a callback: `function callFunc(func) { func() }` and then call it as `callFunc(object.a.test)`.